# Google Drive + ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent, google-drive-api

It appears that Google Drive has an activity that responds to the GET_CONTENT action, but that it's not exported.

Is there another method that I can use in my app to pull content out of Drive, without having to initiate the process *from* Drive? Writing a picker/chooser activity myself and using the backend APIs to list and open a file is obviously an option, but I'd much rather use Drive's own UI to do that.

Comment: Ugh. I have reported this to the Google Drive team: https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/drive/siSKHXdE-ao/discussion

Comment: Thanks, Mark. On the latest version of Drive (1.1.470.15), the Drive team appear to have marked the activity in question as enabled="false". That at least solves the SecurityException, but does nothing for actually enabling the workflow I'm shooting for.

Comment: The `android:enabled="false"` may be temporary, waiting for the app to be configured first: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/12/26/disable-unusable-activities.html

Comment: Interesting, nice insight (and what coincidence on timing). I'm still not seeing it show up in an Intent.chooser for ACTION_GET_CONTENT and an unrestricted mimeType, however. Either way it'd still be useless to me. Humbug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Drive only has an activity that supports `GET_CONTENT` to support pre-API 19 devices. As per the [Storage Access Framework guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#custom), the `GET_CONTENT` activity must be disabled on API 19+ devices to prevent a duplicate with the [DocumentsProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider.html).

The whole point of the Storage Access Framework is that it provides a single UI (started when you use `startActivity` with a `GET_CONTENT`, `OPEN_DOCUMENT`, or `OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` Intent) that allows users to pick from **any** source, including local storage, Google Drive, or any other app. And your app can then access the selected file(s) using the exact same code.

There is no functionality that allows you to specify that only a single root (such as Google Drive) should appear. Users will always be able to select from any available root.

Comment: Just an FYI... your answer is for a question from 2012, before API Level 19 existed. Your answer certainly seems correct for today, but the issue from 2012 was an entirely different matter.