# File View from Google Drive Android Intent

Tags: android, google-drive-api

If anyone can help I would be really awesome. I am building an app where by I am trying to access my files and display them in an imageview.

I have a button and to that I attach an onClickListener

```
iButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(photoPickerIntent, "Select Picture"), 1);
   }
 });
```

The intent gives me 3 options Gallery, Dropbox and Google Drive

For the Gallery I am able to access the file lis this and display it in the imageview

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null,   null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();
imageHolder.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

For Dropbox I do it like this

```
imageHolder.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImage.getPath()));
```

However I am unsure of how to do it for google drive i tried to do it like the gallery but I get the following error

E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What I discovered so far: the Uri returned is in the format: `content://com.google.android.apps.docs.files/exposed_content/[base64-encoded-bytes]`. `[base64-encoded-bytes]` is in fact a reversed, line-feed-and-semi-colon separated URL-encoded string, eg. `123...%3D%3D%0A%3B456...` should be decoded into `456...123...==` Base64-decoding `456...123...==` results in 64 bytes of data, but I can't understand what those bytes are. Here's an example of the resulting 64-bytes I got: http://cl.ly/3Y2C1s0v3O0Q And it doesn't make more sense in HEX: http://goo.gl/7WV9K

Comment: Did you try any of the official documentation? https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui

Answer (score 3):

Correct answer was given originally here: [Google Drive GET_CONTENT intent read file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897179/google-drive-get-content-intent-read-file)

solution is to get it from contentResolver as `InputStream`

My full code to get image from whatever:

```
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
if (selectedImage == null) {
    return;
}
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    mCurrentPhotoPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
}

if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mCurrentPhotoPath)) {
    mCurrentPhotoPath = selectedImage.getPath();
}
Bitmap bitmap = null;
if (imageReturnedIntent.getDataString() != null && imageReturnedIntent.getDataString().contains("docs.file")) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

if (bitmap == null) {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
}
```

Comment: `Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);` throws exception. This is not the solution.

Comment: Roger, I just tried your solution and it worked. I had previously been using the ContentResolver to query the filepath of the content returned from the GET_CONTENT ACTION then opening as a file, which worked for all sources except Google Drive. Thanks!

Comment: What about when
"java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.docs.sync.filemanager.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{42348288 30992:com.app.app/u0a10253} (pid=30992, uid=10253) that is not exported from uid 10015"
is thrown?

Comment: @igordcard i think it's better to read Documentation of FileProvide and exlore source code.

Comment: this does not work for me either. i get the same permission denial

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this can be like beating your head against a wall. Due to some drive side api [idiosyncrasies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063003/google-drive-action-get-content),  you might run into trouble using ACTION_GET_CONTENT. I ended up throwing in a hack to launch from that context menu and just used the [standard integration code](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Right now you cannot be using ACTION_GET_CONTENT in Google Drive. It was wrongly supported by Google in the older version. But latest version of Drive (1.1.470.15) the intents have been disabled and ACTION_GET_CONTENT will not throw up Drive as an option.

Read below the issue discussion.
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/siSKHXdE-ao/discussion

Comment: I have 1.2.228.32, and the Drive option appears when I start an ACTION_GET_CONTENT Intent.

Comment: Then i guess Google guys have to take care of this. Do raise an issue on google for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open any file which you have retrieved from Drive, then this can be done easily while using the resources of Google Drive app. First of all install the Google Drive app from play market [Install Google Drive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs)

After that use this code to open your file.

```
   FileID=file.getId();//it is your file ID which you want to display

  String url = "https://docs.google.com/file/d/"+FileID;
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
   startActivity(i);
```

> It will display your file of any type(image, pdf, doc, txt etc)