# How to read the csv file which is pick from GoogleDrive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

In my android application i have used google drive to pick the file, successfully i can get the content uri, but having trouble to read the file

below is my content URI

```
URI = content://com.google.android.apps.docs.files/exposed_content/qAJe%2Bv7DxEtFhc1liRudRA%3D%3D%0A%3BPE4h2Nrj6pmZwlvaI5ZUguH%2FgG6RxwwptVeTWBME4TLn8eY5ejaqJ0EXiaMxbkY%2B%0A
```

The way i have used to read the file is below

```
Uri _uri = data.getData();
    File file = new File(_uri.getPath());
    ArrayList<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();

        BufferedReader mBufferedReader = null;
        String line;
        try {
            mBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
            while ((line = mBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                records.add(line);
            }
            mBufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Always i got File Not Found Exception

My Logcat

```
03-18 10:13:26.947: W/System.err(24044): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /exposed_content/qAJe+v7DxEtFhc1liRudRA==
03-18 10:13:26.947: W/System.err(24044): ;PE4h2Nrj6pmZwlvaI5ZUguH/gG6RxwwptVeTWBME4TLn8eY5ejaqJ0EXiaMxbkY+
03-18 10:13:26.947: W/System.err(24044): : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-18 10:13:26.947: W/System.err(24044):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
03-18 10:13:26.947: W/System.err(24044):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
03-18 10:13:26.947: W/System.err(24044):    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:42)
```

Please help me to get rid of this problem

Comment: Post log cat details

Comment: Make sure that you have added this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Yes i have added in my manifest

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk & http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Storage_Access_Framework_Example

Comment: Thanks for the link, let me check it out

Comment: Not able to conclude the issue with that link. can you provide any other idea? Note : i have the content URI of that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This below code is helped me to read the file from content uri

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(contents.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line);
}
String contentsAsString = builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files might help you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Orkun Koçyiğit provides a simpler way  to do it in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897179/google-drive-get-content-intent-read-file) thread (without using the GDrive API)