# Security Exception with Google Drive and ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android

In my app users may import sounds, videos, images and other files.
The import is done using standard Intents, and the result handed in OnActivityResult

I am experiencing a security exception when trying to import files from Google Drive on my 4.2.2 tablet, files from other sources such as Dropbox, Onedrive, Gallery etc are all working OK.
Importing from Drive works fine on my 4.4 tablet.

The intent code looks like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.title_dialog_selectphoto)), SELECT_PICTURE_REQUEST);
```

Then in my `importPhotoFromUri(uri)` method I try to open the uri as an inputStream:

```
...
InputStream is;
try {
    is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
....
```

At which point I get a Security Exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
com.google.android.apps.docs.sync.filemanager.FileProvider 
from ProcessRecord{216d9060 18832:com.app.app/u0a10153}
(pid=18832, uid=10153) that is not exported from uid 10179
```

I've found a few posts that seem to refer to a similar problem from a while ago:

[Google Drive + ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063003/google-drive-action-get-content)

[File View from Google Drive Android Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992461/file-view-from-google-drive-android-intent/)

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/siSKHXdE-ao/discussion

But none of these appear to have a solution, other than perhaps re-implementing the Google Drive Integration myself using their API. I'd rather avoid that and keep the user experience simple though.

From the exception tracking in my Google Analytics it looks as though this issue primarily affects users running 4.2.2 devices, I see only 3 security exceptions from other Android versions.
I also see virtually no Security Exceptions prior to May 9th (2014), which is also the date that user igorcard made his comment asking about the same exception on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18298298/2214992

The last update to the Google Drive App on my 4.2.2 device was on the 8th May

I've also been able to observe the same problem in other apps, by trying to load images from my Drive, not just in my own app.

My question then is, can I implement the drive integration another way, without dramatically changing the User Experience, or am I left with just handling the exception and putting up an apologetic Alert Dialog?
Also, has this been broken by the recent update to Drive app or are the timings of the Drive update and the occurrences of this exception in my analytics just coincidental?

Comment: It looks like this was just a bug with **version 1.3.144.17**. They seemed to have fixed it (probably a manifest change) in the latest **version 1.3.222.29** which was released on June 18th 2014.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing the same thing. At least I learnt a lot about Drive SDK these last two weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. The exception is thrown because there is an export false in Google drive manifest to manage the get content intent. It's unreliable to use it. At the end I used Google Drive API and in detail you can see `newOpenFileActivityBuilder()` method an example [docs](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/PickFolderWithOpenerActivity.java)

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid that so that I can keep the simple chooser menu for users to import files from all available places such as Dropbox, Gallery, etc.

Comment: I can understand. I had _exactly_ the same problem, if you want a reliable approach you have to implement that. However it's not really complicated even if it's more code than a simple intent.

Comment: I've sort of followed your advice, and added a bit. Using [this tutorial](http://pilcrowpipe.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/creating-custom-android-intent-chooser.html) I made a custom intent chooser which I show only on devices where the Drive FileProvider is not exported. This chooser then uses Drive SDK and newOpenFileActivityBuilder() as suggested.

Comment: Accept the response please if it's ok for you